# How to match PTR record with a different domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

I am a bit confused about PTR records and how to set it up correctly.

This is the current setup:

A website: domain.com, on this website I have a mailaddress info@domain.com.
On domain.com I have an iframe which shows a questionaire, this questionaire is hosted on otherdomain.com.

At some point in the questionaire users will get a confirmation mail from the sender info@domain.com which is sent from a mailserver at smtp.otherdomain.com.

- On domain.com I have added the IP for smtp.otherdomain.com in my SPF record.
- On domain.com I have a PTR record set to the IP of the server it is hosted on
- On otherdomain.com there is a PTR record set to smtp.otherdomain.com

In most cases sending mails goes fine, however last week I got this message:
550 inconsistent or no DNS PTR record for << The IP of otherdomain.com >>

The mails did not end up in the inbox of '@freenet.de' mail accounts.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

@Gerb You are trying to send out mail from info@domain.com through smtp.otherdomain.com. To make sure your mails work, you only require the following.

- SPF record allowing smtp.otherdomain.com as allowed sender (which you already did)
- PTR record for sending server smtp.otherdomain.com (if the IP of smtp.otherdomain.com is 111.222.111.222 then there should be a PTR record for 111.222.111.222 pointing to smtp.otherdomain.com/)

**Note**

- Please note that if you have multiple IPs using which smtp.otherdomain.com server sends out emails, there should be PTRs for all IPs.
- Here smtp.otherdomain.com is the name of your mailserver. (for eg. myhostname of postfix or content of /var/qmail/me in qmail)

Comment: Just to be completely sure. The PTR records only need to be on the otherdomain.com, correct?

Comment: No the PTR record should be the name of the mail server, Please see the note section of the answer.

Comment: The in A and ptr must match the mx record of the domain. meaning : if your domain1.com has mx.mailer.com as mx so mx.mailer.com must match the aame ip in forward (in A) and reverse (ptr) to the same ip that its not regionized as spam